# Como desativar a tela cheia de outro programa?

Tags: c, c++, fullscreen

Por exemplo, um jogo que está em tela cheia (Com tela cheia não quero dizer maximizado, e sim "fullscreen mesmo"). Como faço pra ficar em modo janela com C++ ?

Já tentei usando "SendMessage" :

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(88))
        {
            HWND hWnd = GetActiveWindow();
            SendMessageA(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_RESTORE, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Mas não deu certo.